# Display multiple columns in one to many relationship

Tags: sql, t-sql, one-to-many

I'm a new to Sql and have the following scenario. Suppose I have the two tables - Employee and Address which are as shown respectively:

| EmployeeID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jason Malloy |
| 2 | Andra Tully |
| 3 | Linda Tarwater |

| AddressID | EmployeeID | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 89 Daphne St |
| 2 | 3 | 1054 Us 56 Hwy |
| 3 | 1 | 2627 Theresa Ln |
| 4 | 2 | 1438 Logsden Rd |
| 5 | 2 | 286 Elliott Rd |
| 6 | 1 | 10561 Claussen St |

I want to write a query that displays each employee as well as up to 3 of their addresses (in no particular order) so that the output will look something like the following:

| Employee | Address1 | Address2 | Address3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jason Malloy | 89 Daphne St | 2627 Theresa Ln | 10561 Claussen St |
| Andra Tully | 1438 Logsden Rd | 286 Elliott Rd | NULL |
| Linda Tarwater | 1054 Us 56 Hwy | NULL | NULL |

I tried self-joining the address table 3 times, but this yielded many duplicate entries

```
SELECT Name, A.Address AS Address1, B.Address AS Address2, C.Address AS Address3
FROM Employee
LEFT JOIN Address A ON Employee.EmployeeID = A.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN Address B ON A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN Address C ON B.EmployeeID = C.EmployeeID
```

Comment: This looks like a typical *Pivot* - have you searched on that topic?

Comment: You get duplicates because you are joined a row to itself and all other rows for the same employee multiple times; you end up with n³ rows per employee, where *n* is the number of addresses in the table for a single employee.

Answer (score 0):

You can have many addresses per employee of which you want to show up to three.

Here is one approach:

1. Number your addresses per employee.
2. Pivot the addresses #1, #2, and #3 from rows into columns.
3. Join the three addresses to the employee.

The query:

```
WITH address_numbered AS
(
  SELECT
    employeeid,
    address,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employeeid ORDER BY address) AS rn
  FROM address
)
, three_addresses AS
(
  SELECT
    employeeid,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN address END) AS address1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN address END) AS address2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN address END) AS address3
  GROUP BY employeeid
)
SELECT e.name, a.address1, a.address2, a.address3
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN three_addresses a ON a.employeeid = e.employeeid
ORDER BY e.name;
```